# How to simulate the hover effect of the web in a ppt slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to simulate the hover effect of some websites ... This effect is that when you hover the mouse over a button it grows a little, but when you leave it ... it returns to its original size.

So that there is hover over said element, and it grows a little, I make it run this macro when the mouse passes over it, so far so good, but how can I make it run another macro that reduces it when the mouse leaves he?

At first the idea came to me to put a shape that surrounds it and that has no fill or border and that runs when the mouse passes over it, but then I thought that when I want to hover over the button first I would have to go through that and reduce it first before increasing by hover effect. At the moment I can't think of another way, any ideas? or someone who has already been through this?

PD: I was checking ActionSettings, but it only has ppMouseClick and ppMouseOver and what I'm looking for is that it runs when the mouse leaves the area in some way.

Comment: If PowerPoint has only ppMouseClick and ppMouseOver, then that's all you have to work with.

Answer (score 0):

> At first the idea came to me to put a shape that surrounds it and that has no fill or border and that runs when the mouse passes over it, but then I thought that when I want to hover over the button first I would have to go through that and reduce it first before increasing by hover effect

You've got the right idea. Assign a mouseover macro to the surrounding shape, something like this (aircode):

```
' Globally ...
Dim bTriggered as Boolean

Sub SurroundingShape()
   
   If bTriggered Then 
      ' mouse has passed over me already
      ' cursor is LEAVING the button area
   Else
      ' mouse is entering the button area
      Call MacroThatMakesTheButtonBounce
   End If

   bTriggered = Not bTriggered

End Sub
```